# Importing MBOX file in Outlook 2010 (or converting to PST)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, pst, mbox

I exported my e-mails from an old Gmail account using Google Takeout. The exported e-mails are now in an MBOX file. I somehow need to import this into MS Outlook 2010. Of course, it's also fine to convert the MBOX file to a PST file, so I can open that in Outlook.

All advice is welcome, because so far I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: The absolute easiest thing to do, if the Gmail account is still valid, is to connect your Outlook client to the Gmail account and download all of the messages to a PST file. Is there a reason you haven't tried this?

Comment: @music2myear I haven't tried it, because it requires me to setup 2-factor authentication and I didn't really wanna get into that. But it seems that is indeed the best way to go.

Comment: If you have 2-Factor enabled on your Google account, you can still set up App passwords which don't require 2-Factor to work. Have you tried that?

Comment: No, I haven't because then I still need to setup 2-factor auth :P. But I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Gmail account still exists, the easiest thing would be to simply connect the Outlook client to the Gmail account, then download all of the messages to a PST file.

If 2-Factor authentication is enabled on your account, you can create app-specific passwords in your Google Account settings, under Sign-In and Security. These will allow setting up your account in Outlook without requiring 2-Factor in that application.

Answer (score -3):

There's a MBOX Converter on TechNet that may work for you.

[TechNet Link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Learn-How-to-Import-MBOX-40f45897)

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.